# Woodburning stove / heater in a van

Tags: heater, conversion, campervan

I am planning to install a mini wood burning stove in my van. Has anyone here have any experience with doing this?

I have found a very small one on ebay, which I really like. The flue outlet is 63.5mm (2 1/2") so I can use exhaust pipe as flue pipe, but should the bit outside the van be double/twin walled? I am worried that in the cold weather it will not draw... would this really be an issue bearing in mind that the overall length of the flue will be not more than 2m, including the outside.

Thanks in advance,

Leo

Comment: Get a carbon monoxide detector so you don't die in your sleep.

Comment: and make sure you have a fresh air inlet sufficiently sized...

Comment: To whomever voted to close this, would like to remind everyone *vehicle accessories are on-topic*. This may be an *unorthodox* accessory, but it is an accessory, nonetheless. Please refer to the [Help Center](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) if you have any questions.